# Printing a Local String in C

Tags: c

I was confused with this C code in a test question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Data {
    char var1;
    char var2;
    char varArr[10];
};

int main() {
    union Data data;
    data.var1 = 'a';
    data.var2 = 'b';
    data.varArr[0] = 'c';
    char ctr[3];
    ctr[0] = data.var1;
    ctr[1] = data.var2;
    ctr[2] = data.varArr[0];
    printf("Result: %s\n", ctr);
    return 0;
}
```

The question I saw asked me what this code would print, and the obvious answer was `ccc`, but the fact that the array's length is 3 and all of the elements are just `c` bugged me (no `\0` in the end).

I thought that maybe it could print some garbage sometimes and other times it would work as expected, but after trying a few times, I saw that it always works as expected.

After that, I decided to go out of bounds and check what the following bytes after the array had, specifically in `ctr[3]`, `ctr[4]` and `ctr[5]`, to go a little further. I noticed that these bytes are generally, but not always, `\0`. When they are not `\0`, they generally take small garbage values like `0x01` or `0x04` (Are they really garbage values in this case? I don't know), but again, `ccc` was printed in those cases, as well.

I have no clue why this happens. I first thought that maybe some word-size chunk allocation stuff causes the following bytes to be zero, but after seeing they could sometimes be nonzero left me clueless.

After that, I tried to simplify the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ctr[3];
    ctr[0] = 'c';
    ctr[1] = 'c';
    ctr[2] = 'c';
    printf("Result: %s\n", ctr);
    return 0;
}
```

This code printed `cccX` (X is some garbage value that seemed to be changing both in size and content on different runs.) So, the two codes have some differences in memory caused by the local `data` variable in the first code, but I couldn't figure out how.

Why and how does this happen?

I used gcc 13 as my compiler on a 64-bit machine, if it helps.

PS: I was kind of expecting an explanation in terms of what is allocated in memory in what order, instead of just calling it undefined behavior. The local variables are close to each other in terms of memory locations, afaik. Maybe the things written in the place of `data` affected the working of printing `ctr` in some way. but if UB is the furthest answer I can get, I also want to know why. Thanks for the UB explanations :)

Comment: Unrelated: you can print a char array without a `'\0'` terminator with `printf("%.3s", (char[3]){'c', 'c', 'c'}); /* no UB here */`

Comment: @pnguib -- Creating strings with no terminating NUL ('\0') and printing them is undefined behavior.  Sometimes you'll get what you expect and sometimes you won't.  Because it works sometimes is not a good reason to persist with it.

Comment: Hi @pmg  -- sorry if I gave any impression my comment was directed at you (it wasn't -- it was for OP -- Updated my last comment for clarification.  Thx)

Comment: Yeah @gregspears .. I figured that after I wrote the 2nd comment (which I deleted in the meanwhile). My apologies :)

Comment: @pmg -- we're good.  Thx for standing up with apology (but not rqrd).  We could use a lot more of that spirit in the community.

Comment: @pnguib, "check what the following bytes after the array had, specifically in ctr[3], ctr[4] and ctr[5]" --> How did you do that?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `printf("Result: %x\n", ctr[3]);` gives an hex code of the char there. I simply put a stmt like this just to see what's there.

Comment: @gregspears Thanks for the answer :) I was expecting some analysis of memory allocations and locations of the local variables wrt each other, though. I've included it to the PS. Sorry for the lack of explanation of what I was expecting.

Comment: @pnguib -- Understood.  OK, we can't really be sure about the memory address of each of the local variables -- they will almost always change at runtime.  Although you can inspect those addresses with printf().  But more importantly, here is what's going on:  printf keeps reading memory after the last 'c' character in the array - it is looking for the terminating NUL which we did not provide.  "Reading off the end of the array" which is extremely dangerous.   And so it's finding whatever is in memory after the array, accessing what it cannot legally access.   Anything can happen -- this is UB.

Comment: @pnguib Note that `printf("Result: %x\n", ctr[3]);` itself is _undefined behavior_ (UB) as attempting to read `ctr[3]` is UB.

Comment: @gregspears We can't know their locations but I thought maybe we can have some clue about their relative locations. Is that also impossible? Because they are constant in size and thus the space on the call stack everything will accumulate is known and can be calculated in compile-time, so (I'm not sure, but) maybe they are always in locations such that their _relative locations_ are the same? Because, you know, same compiled code makes the same allocations, even if the addresses may be different from run to run.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I know. That line is just for seeing the memory contents close to `ctr` and does not exist in the actual code. What I'm asking is slightly different. When there is some local variable (like in the first case) the behavior of the code seems to be not that _UB_, just as if `printf` always stops at some point and it looked like `data` is causing this. Can we focus on that side of the problem?

Comment: @pnguib --  I get you.  I learned a long time ago that compilers generally place statically allocated memory declarations near each other in memory -- *kind of* the same as they are laid out in your C Code.  Experiments like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/PszfYPKoh) help to illustrates this -- notice what gets printed this time.... can you explain it?  I bet you can.  *I have to emphasize that this is educational only, and very bad practice.*   But I understand, you are hungry to know things, and it reminds me of me. :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the values of uninitialized variables are indeterminate. They *may* be `0`, but they might be any other value valid for the data type. If you are using `%s` with `printf` without a width limit, not supplying a null-terminated string leads to [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Reading out of bounds on an array also invokes UB.

One of the most dangerous UB situations is when your program *appears* to work normally. This can lead to faulty assumptions about expected behaviour, and those expectations are always dashed at the worst possible times, in my experience.

Comment: Quibble... "*Yes, the values of uninitialized variables [having automatic storage duration] are indeterminate.*" [C18 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization(p10)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.7.9) *"If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate."*  (that said, I knew what you meant, but we must take care not to leave those learning with assertions that only hold some of the time `:)`

Answer (score 4):

`%s` tells `printf()` that the corresponding argument is to be treated as a string (a 0-terminated sequence of `char`), which `ctr` is not, resulting in an unexpected (undefined) outcome.